# External Links from Flash Carousel

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to create a Flash Carousel in AS2. I've made the Carousel itself, and have got the icon images and tooltips from an XML file using this code:

```
xml.onLoad = function()
{
    var nodes = this.firstChild.childNodes;
    numOfItems = nodes.length;
    for(var i=0;i<numOfItems;i++)
    {
        var t = home.attachMovie("item","item"+i,i+1);
        t.angle = i * ((Math.PI*2)/numOfItems);
        t.onEnterFrame = mover;
        t.toolText = nodes[i].attributes.tooltip;
        t.url = nodes[i].attributes.url;
        t.icon.inner.loadMovie(nodes[i].attributes.image);
        t.r.inner.loadMovie(nodes[i].attributes.image);
        t.icon.onRollOver = over;
        t.icon.onRollOut = out;
        t.icon.onRelease = released;
    }
}
```

I have functions for 'over', 'out', and 'released', and to move the carousel automatically, left or right depending on mouse position.

I was wondering if there was a way you could make each individual icon have an external link that leads to a different place on my website when you click on an icon, where I could specify the link url itself in the XML file?

If you need more of the code for context purposes then please don't hesitate to ask. I hope you can help.

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you might be after [flashvars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Flash vars is what I meant. I meant how I would I get a URL from the XML document such as:

```
<icons>
    <icon image="icon1.jpg" tooltip="Ramis Assets" url="www.myramis.com" />
</icons>
```

and then use that URL to navigate to that URL in a browser when it is clicked on.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of URLs. You already have a means to grab the URL from the XML file:

```
nodes[i].attributes.url;
```

Then store it under the index i. Then when it is clicked (perhaps in the release function), do a quick search of the array to find the correct one and then:

```
window.location = correctURL;
```

You may have to store the currently selected index to reference against.